# Find the greatest distance from a point on the cardioid to the Ox axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a>0$ and let $C$ be the set defined by: $C={(x,y)|x^2+y^2=2a(x+\sqrt(x^2+y^2)}$. Find the greatest distance from a point on the cardioid to the $Ox$ axis.

I used the usual parametrisation( polar coordinates) for the $x,y$ and I found the length of the curve, it is $4a$ using line integrals of the first kind, but there is where my knowledge stops.
I am new to this type of problems and I do not have many examples, could you provide a full proof, or at least in the form of an answer, such that it would serve as a model for similar problems I encounter? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Don't post unsearchable images.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.  Solution:  just consider the $y$ component, and find its maximum value by high-school calculus methods.

Comment: Ok, David, I changed my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

The polar equation of the cardioid is $2a(1+\cos\theta)$, and the distance of a point of the curve to the $x$-axis is
$$|x|=|r\sin\theta|=2a|\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)|,$$
so you only have to determine the maximum value of $|\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)|$.